# Thumb drive: performance, web browsers, disk reads and writes

Tags: partitioning, usb, performance, disk, browser

This is added 3 hours after the original post.   I tried another flash drive.   Sandisk 64 gb.   Performance is resolved.   Apparently the PNY drive labeled/marked as 3.0 is not equivalent to the Sandisk 64 gb device I tried later.   Both devices had been purchased in the past 3 months.   The one with bad performance had been used for a short time in a Roku TV.   The Sandisk thumb drive is partitioned with an ext4 partition for Lubuntu and a swap partition.   It works fine.   I partitioned the PNY the same as the Sandisk and reinstalled.   Performance with the PNY is still BAD

-----------------   Start of original post/question -------------

Lubuntu 19.04.  Installed from thumb drive (USB 3.0 32 gb Yumi UEFI) to USB 3.0 64 gb.   Partitions are 200 mb fat32 (/boot/efi), 50 gb ext2 (/) and 8 gb fat32 mounts on /media , no swap.   Test system is Core I5 gen 7, 16 gb memory.   System boots and plays.  Performance is intermittently sluggish and appears to be related to DISK I/O.  When performance is bad the LED in/on the thumb drive is flashing constantly.  Installed "iotop" and confirmed web browsers (firefox, chrome) do a lot more writing to the disk than I expect.  Disabled "lxqt Power Management" because it appeared to be contributing to disk i/o.

My goal is to use the thumb drive as a portable dokuwiki/demonstration.   I have installed apache, it works and am stumbling through the dokuwiki self-education process.   Demonstrating dokuwiki with a web browser, booted from the thumb drive, appears problematic given that disk activity gets in the way of performance.

I am not using a casper-rw file system.  Does anyone know that casper-rw does not exhibit similar disk i/o behavior.

Has anyone else seen this behavior on thumb drives?  Should I use ext3 or ext4 for "/" and/or allocate a swap partition.   Memory utilization never approaches the 16 gb of the test system, so I am assuming swap is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-) The following links may add some details, [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed) and [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312).

Answer (score 0):

What you're experiencing is related to the NAND technology underlying your USB stick and is unrelated to the USB standard.

#### The short answer:

All USB sticks are created equal *but some are more equal than others!*  E.G. a USB 2 SLC stick is faster than a USB 3 QLC one.

#### The long answer:

The [USB standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) defines the connectors, cabling, power consumption and signalling and defines the ***maximum speed*** a device can work at.

The underlying [NAND memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell) defines the ***minimum speed*** at which the USB stick works:

- SLC: four times as reliable and four times as fast as QLC and *four times as expansive to manufacture*
- MLC: half the speed and half the reliability of SLC *but half the price*
- TLC: 1/3 the speed and 1/3 the reliability of SLC *but 1/3 of the price*
- QLC: 1/4 the speed and 1/4 the reliability of SLC *but 1/4 of the price*

As you didn't mention any part numbers, I'm guessing that the SAN-Disk is using MLC and the PNY one is using QLC (SLC USB sticks are hard to come by nowadays and are not generally stocked and need to be ordered)